# How to create nested tag in JSON

Tags: php, json

I have been fiddling with JSON nested tag, tried the basics now I want to go a little further, but it has been giving a little head ache to me. I have this public function below

```
   public function returnResponse($code, $data){
    header("content-type: application/json");
    $result = json_encode(['response' => ['status' => $code, "message"  => $data]]);
    echo $result ; exit;        

}
      $order= $cust->getDeliveryDetail();
```

USING `print_r($order);`

```
      Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [order_id] => 4444
                    [menu] => two
                    [order_uniq] => 999oeo4

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pro_name] => Beans
                    [pro_sub] => Goods
                    [pro_type] => Open CA
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [pro_name] => Rice
                    [pro_sub] => Fiber
                    [pro_type] => Diverca
                )

        )

)
```

then attaching object with elements and value which references

```
     $result ['order_id'] = $order[0][0]['order_id'];   
      $result ['menu'] = $order[0][0]['menu'];  
      $result ['order_uniq'] = $order[0][0]['order_uniq'];
      $result ['pro_name'] = $order[0][0]['pro_name'];
      $result ['pro_sub'] = $order[0][0]['pro_sub'];
     $result ['pro_type'] = $order[0][0]['pro_type'];

     $this->returnResponse(SUCCESS_RESPONSE, $result); //THIS IS THE ORIGINAL BEGINNING PUBLIC FUNCTION WE CREATED
```

to create this JSON nested tag below

```
     {
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "message": {
            "order_id": "4444",
            "menu": "two",
            "order_uniq": "999oeo4",
            "pro_name": "Beans",
            "pro_sub": "Goods",
            "pro_type": "Openca",
          }
    }
}
```

but I want to create a JSON nested tag like this below

```
    {
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "message": {
            "order_id": "4444",
            "menu": "two",
            "order_uniq": "999oeo4",
            "items": [
            {
            "pro_name": "Beans",
            "pro_sub": "Goods",
            "pro_type": "Openca",
            }
            {
            "pro_name": "Rice",
            "pro_sub": "Fiber",
            "pro_type": "Diverca",
            }    
            ]
    },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$result = array(
    'order_id' = > $order[0][0]['order_id'],
    'menu' => $order[0][0]['menu'],  
    'order_uniq' => $order[0][0]['order_uniq'],
    'pro_name' => $order[0][0]['pro_name'],
    'pro_sub' => $order[0][0]['pro_sub'],
    'pro_type' => $order[0][0]['pro_type'],
    'items' => array()
);

foreach($order[1] as $item) {
    array_push(
        $result['items'],
        array(
            'pro_name' => $item['pro_name'],
            'pro_sub' => $item['pro_sub'],
            'pro_type' => $item['pro_type'],
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it helps -- maybe not, the right way to do this in the beginning would be to create an OrderItems table/dictionary. Then store items in that table referrencing your Order table with "order_id". That way you could pull order_items as one array object, and convert that to json really simply.

Here since, you are getting "pro_name", "pro_sub" & "pro_type" as items, you would programmatically pull those out and create your own order_items array.

```
$order= $cust->getDeliveryDetail();
$order_id = $order[0][0]['order_id'];
$order_menu = $order[0][0]['menu'];
$order_uniq = $order[0][0]['order_uniq'];

$items = [];
foreach($order[1] as $order_item) {
    $items[] = $order_item;
}

$result = [];
$result["order_id"] = $order_id;
$result["menu"] = $order_menu;
$result["order_uniq"] = $order_uniq;
$result["order_items"] = $items;

$this->returnResponse(SUCCESS_RESPONSE, $result);
```

Comment: as of php 5.4, you can use $items = [], and $result = []. Else you would need to do $items = array(), and $result = array()